# Attempt to read property on int

Tags: php, laravel

My relations:

Content mode =>

```
class Content extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "contents";

    protected $fillable = [ "body", "camapaign_id" ];

    public function campaigns(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class, "campaign_id");
    }
}
```

My camapaign model =>

```
class Campaign extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "campaigns";

    protected $fillable = [ "ringba_campaign_id", "is_active" ];

    public function contents(){
        return $this->hasMany(Content::class, "content_id");
    }
}
```

Here are my migrations:

content table =>

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("body", 255);
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Campaign::class)->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Campaign table =>

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("ringba_campaign_id", 255);
            $table->boolean("is_active")->default(0);
        });
    }
```

Here is my content controller:

```
 public function index(){
        $contents = Content::all()->sortBy("created_at");
        return view("Dashboard.Contents.contents", [
            "contents" => $contents
        ]);
    }
```

I am trying to access ringba_camapaign_id in here like this =>

```
 @foreach($contents as $content) 
  {{ $content->campaign_id->ringba_campaign_id }}
 @endforeach
```

But I am getting this error : Attempt to read property on int

Comment: one thing is here typo  {{ $content->camapaign_id>ringba_campaign_id }} to  {{ $content->camapaign_id->ringba_campaign_id }}. instead of ->ringba_campaign_id,you have >ringba_campaign_id..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you @JohnLobo

Comment: look like you have edited question.now typo fixed

Comment: Yes I misspelled those sorry for that mistake

Comment: add controller code also.look like it should  be  {{ $content->campaigns->ringba_campaign_id }}

Comment: `content->campaign_id` just returns the id as an integer, not a model. You could have to do something like `Campaign::find($content->campaign_id)->ringba_campaign_id` to access it through the model

Comment: ok I am adding the controller code also

Comment: @JohnLobo Qustion updated

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not check what `$content->campaign_id` contains?

Comment: I get the campaign id if I echo this $content->campaign_id. But when I tried to fetch ringba_campaign_id which is inside the CampaignModel I get this error.

Comment: I strongly invite you to read this part of the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I wrote bad relation code inside content model:

Before I wrote:

```
public function campaigns(){
return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class);
}
```

Answer will be :

```
 public function campaign(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class);
    }
```

I wrote campaigns instead of campaign.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things here, since Content BelongsTo a Campaign the method should be singular.

```php
public function campaign(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class, 'campaign_id');
}
```

Then when you do `$content->campaign_id` you are getting the property on the model and so is returning an int. What you want to do is return the campaign model like so `$content->campaign` through the relationship defined in the Content model. Now you can access the property on the campaign model, `$content->campaign->ringba_campaign_id`.

However it also looks like a campaign can be nullable by your migration so you would need to add protection from this so you don't get property on null errors. So this would look like `optional($content->campaign)->ringba_campaign_id`, this would then return null if the Content didn't have a Campaign.

Comment: Thanks man already figured it out. but still thanks I am ticking it as the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
@foreach($contents as $content) 
  {{ $content->campaigns->ringba_campaign_id }}
@endforeach
```

for more information check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it